# Can't display my blog Posts as a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I designed my application for displaying the latest news  about my youtube videos

So i added  an extra  Activity  which should  display  my blog posts  as a recycler view + List view  for  the latest news. But it didn't work properly.

Help!

Comment: Google for recyclerview ;-).

Comment: Post some code that you tried and explain more about the issue.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to know how to ask